# Remove the new kernel

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, cpu-usage

I was working without any problem and one day the computer didn't start he said that there is a problem in the Xserver , so I connected to my computer through ssh and reinstalled xserver-xorg ,xserver-xorg-core then The computer start working but when I tap the touchpad it's don't click (it's not a configuration problem) so i copied the drivers from another linux mint and copied them into mine , and in that moment i found that i have the kernel 4.2.0-32 installed but it's not in my friend computer then I tried to uninstall it but it was impossible then I've installed the kernel 4.4.0-22 now the the touchpad is working but youtube in chrome show black video , I've changed something in the configuration about harware acceleration and now it's fine now the computer work without any problem except it's working so slowly I'm just using a browser and i'm using 60% from my CPU

**so I want to go back to the kernel 3.19.0-32 because it's recommended and the problem is that I can't uninstall the current kernel because it's loaded so i want to know how can i load another installed kernel to be able to delete the current one ? (Current kernel 4.4.0-22)**

*Here i can delete the old kernel because it's not loaded*
[image]

*Here i can't delete the new kernel because it's loaded (I want to delete it)*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to get your pc to boot from your target kernel. Since both kernels are available on your system they should be available at boot time via Grub (At least I think that's how mint deals with it - I'm using archlinux and it is a bit different :) )

So when you reboot you should have the option, select your preferred kernel  (3.19) from your "advanced options" menu.

Once booted with that kernel, I would check out everything works as smooth as it should, and then get rid of the unwanted kernel.
If, for some reason, you don't get your 3.19 kernel from grub, you'd probably need to run :

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

assuming your grub config is in /boot/grub ...
Maybe start by doing that, just to make sure.